# Crystal report generation using two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am using C#.net 2010, I want to create invoice using two tables. One table `Order` consist of things ordered by customer like category, qty, rate, Total amount, and another table `Details` consist of final amount paid details like Vat, Final total. I have created one data set consist of one data table using following query:

```
SELECT Order*,Details* FROM (Order INNER JOIN Details ON Order.ID = Details.ID)
WHERE(Order.ID = ?)`
```

It's showing "Details" table records multiple times instead of one time, as it consist of unique record of each order. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: could you please post your crystal reports design?

Comment: I have not used crystal report, used simple report

Answer (score 0):

I got its solution, have created this using simple report i.e. using .rdlc file from add new item on solution explorer, then I add dataset, created using query mentioned in my question, then I created two table for `Order` table & `Details` table in .rdlc file from its toolbox menu, after that I removed grouping of `Details` table by selecting its row, right click on it and selcted Row Group-> Delete Group. Finally, attached this .rdlc file to Reportviewer.